# Websphere application server administration service stopped working due to SSL configuration

Tags: ssl, websphere-8

I am working on WebSphere clustering. Everything was working fine. But for SSL, I accidentally change protocol from SSL_TLS to TLSV1.2.

I have changed it here

Security - - SSL certificate and key management - -  SSL configuration - -  CellDefultsetting - QOP - protocol

And now my administrator console is not opening.

Error in logs :

```
CWPKI0028E: SSL handshake protocol "SSLv2" is not valid. This protocol is specified in the SSL configuration alias "CellDefaultSSLSettings" loaded from SSL configuration file "security.xml".

  The extended error message is: "no such algorithm: SSLv2 for provider IBMJSSE2".
```

I checked security.xml in cell, but the value f SSL protocol is still SSL_TLS.

Where do I need to revert the changes done in console? Console is no more opening.

Comment: This is a common problem if client and server do not have common protocol as TLSv1.2. All browser are not TLSv1.2 compliant. Can you please check in browser settings  if your browser is TLSv1.2 compliant and it is enabled.

Comment: Were you able to get admin console working with TLSv1.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure that your browser supports TLSv1.2 and is enabled. If not, try to open admin console from a different browser which supports TLSv1.2.

If you really need to disable admin security so that you can change back the SSL settings, here is a document:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21405302